Typing // in the url doesnt send me to the index, but to a blank page
I have my router set up like this:
<Route path="/" element={<PrivateRoute Route={<Welcome />} />} />
<Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />

The problem occurs when typing // in the url instead of /. It sends me to a blank page. However, when typing more than 2 backslashes, it sends me to my Login page:
<Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />

How can I fix this issue, so that if the user types in more than 1 backslash, to send them to the index page (Welcome page in my case), or if that isn't possible to send them to the NotFound page.

How about adding a default route?

I can't reproduce the issue you describe. Here's a running CodeSandbox demo. That said, "//", "///", and so on, are not valid URL paths, so I'd say it's rather indeterminant how these are handled by RRD.

You can create a component and check the path if it starts with double slash like this
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const RedirectInvalidPath = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    const url = window.location.pathname;
    if (url.startsWith('//')) {
      navigate('/'); 
    }
  }, []);
  return null; 
};
export default RedirectInvalidPath;

{/*and then setup the component in your router */}

    <RedirectInvalidPath/>

